# Import Error on trying to import a submodule that imports a submodule

Tags: python, python-import

I feel like I'm missing something simple and basic. Here's a toy setup

```
PythonProject/
main.py
x/
    a.py
    y/
        b.py
```

b.py has a function foo with no dependencies

```
def foo():
    print("Hello World")
```

a.py needs foo from b.py to work and imports it directly

```
import y.b
def bar():
    #Do some stuff
    y.b.foo()
```

main.py needs bar from a.py

```
import x.a
x.a.bar()
```

Now, running a.py works just fine, it successfully imports b and finds foo.
Trying to run main.py however breaks with an import error: specifically "import b" fails during "import a"

I get the impression that what needs to happen is that `b` needs to be exposed by an `__init__.py` in `a/` but I'm unsure what the pythonic way of doing this would be.

What is the preferred solution to importing a module (a) which imports another module (b) preferably without bringing PythonProject awareness to a?

Comment: I copied your code, verbatim, and the problem is not reproducible. What is the exact error you are receiving? Can we see more code?

Comment: Thank you for replying!

I edited the code in the example to make the directory names different from the file names. When I run the exact code I have posted now, I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import x.a
  File "/Users/rsmirol/PythonProject/x/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import y.b
ImportError: No module named 'y'`

Comment: This happens on `python3 main.py`

Comment: Okay, I will try it now.

Comment: I found a solution! I will post it as an answer.

Comment: do you have any `__init__.py` files?

Comment: In the actual project I have empty `__init__.py` files in the x and y equivalents. They were not necessary for reproducing the same error.

Comment: your `__init__` files should contain import statements that expose the functions you want to make public. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Importing files from different folder in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder-in-python):

### main.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/path/x')
import a
a.bar()
```

### a.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/path/x/y')
import b
def bar():
    #Do some stuff
    b.foo()
```

### b.py

```
def foo():
    print("Hello World")
```

Comment: So to generalize, we could us os to find the absolute path to a module and add it to the python path?

Do you think this is something that makes sense to do in `__init__.py` for the modules?

Comment: @Zaez Don't mess with the path. use `__init__.py` files. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21995949/1552748

Comment: Yes, it could make sense wherever you need to be importing those files. Also, you could always place your most-used files inside the actual Python `libs` directory.

Comment: @PaulH I don't see a solution that works without messing with the path directly or in `__init__.py` files. What am I missing? The problem essentially is that the project root doesn't care about y, but cares about x which cares about y, so when x calls `import y.b' there is an import error that it can't find y.

Comment: each directory needs an init file. each init file should import the functions it wants to expose to the user. there's no need to modify the path.

Comment: @Paul I would argue that editing the `sys.path` is much easier than tediously adding `__init__.py` files to every directory that gets in the way.

Comment: that's not how packages should be built: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: @Paul I see your point, but I don't know that Zaez wants to do anything more than a couple small files. I hardly think that warrants a whole new package setup, but I guess it would work just as well.

Comment: if that were the case, all of these functions would be in a single file at the top-level of the directory structure.

Comment: @Paul Good point! Either way, you should post your solution as an answer as well. That way, it presents two different options to Zaez.

Comment: Thanks for the link @PaulH! I guess my question then becomes, in the example you linked, what if there was a .py file in the top level sound folder which imported from formats/effects/filters? Lets call it audio.py. External to the package, if I wanted to call a function in audio.py, I would not be able to use `from sound.audio import dothething` as the imports in audio.py would result in the same error Im seeing here. What do we do in `_init__.py` to solve that?

Answer (score 4):

This was never properly answered even though Paul H alluded to the answer.

It's very simple and mentioned but not directly stated [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).

If you have a directory like this:

```
sound/                      Top-level package
  __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
  formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
          __init__.py
          wavread.py
          wavwrite.py
          aiffread.py
          aiffwrite.py
          auread.py
          auwrite.py
          ...
  effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
          __init__.py
          echo.py
          surround.py
          reverse.py
          ...
  filters/                  Subpackage for filters
          __init__.py
          equalizer.py
          vocoder.py
          karaoke.py
          ...
```

The `__init__.py` file in (for example "effects") needs to include

```
import effects.echo
import effects.surround
import effects.reverse
```

To call a submodule from within a submodule, as you asked, for example, echo calls surround, then you will need to import surround into echo using
`import effects.surround as surround`

Comment: although - if someone wants to add to this so that a main() function within echo doesn't need to be called with echo.main(arg1, etc) but rather echo(arg1, etc) that'd be great

Comment: If you import `effects.surround as surround` wouldn't that make the module not work when run individually?

Comment: Thank you, I was lost for a good hour. For others stumbling on this, tools like `isort` (and `ruff`) will remove these imports from the `__init__.py` files because of the unused imports rule (ignore these lines by adding `# noqa: F401`).